# Possible reasons why meld cannot access /dev/fd/* when run as unprivileged user?

Tags: permissions

I suspected meld needed them to be also writable. However, it does say `Could not read file` (notice "read"); plus then the implication would be that they are writable for root, because there was no such error for root.

```
~$ diff <(echo foo) <(echo bar)
1c1
< foo
---
> bar

~$ meld <(echo foo) <(echo bar)  # not working, see comment below
~$ sudo -s
~# meld <(echo foo) <(echo bar)  # works just fine
```

The first one returns `Could not read file` and `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/fd/63'`.

What do you suspect is the reason for this behavior?

[image: Screenshot]

Unprivileged user above, root below.

[image: Screenshot, root]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when a Meld window is already open. In that case, running `meld` again tries to use the existing Meld process; but that process can’t access the `/dev/fd` files which are used for the substitution...

There doesn’t seem to be an option to force Meld to use the “new” process, ignoring all others.